# jQuery Range Slider using default attribute values

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider, rangeslider

I am using jquery Range Slider which has the following code.

```
$("#maxAge").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 18,
    max: 75,
    values: [20, 45],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#sliderVal").val(ui.values[0] + "-" + ui.values[1]);
    }
});
$("#sliderVal").val($("#maxAge").slider("values", 0) + "-" + $("#maxAge").slider("values", 1));

<div id="maxAge" min="35" max="75" minVal="25" maxVal="45"></div>
<input type="text" class="slider-text text-right gradient-text mt-2" id="sliderVal" readonly>
```

I want to use it like this:

```
$("#maxAge").slider({
    range: true,
    min: $(this).attr('min'),
    max: $(this).attr('max'),
    values: [$(this).attr('minVal'), $(this).attr('maxVal')],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#sliderVal").val(ui.values[0] + "-" + ui.values[1]);
    }
});
```

I want to fetch the attribute values from the DIV and use it here so that I can later change the attribute values using PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get value of attribute using your_div_id and then use `parseInt()` to parse string as  integer.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("#maxAge").slider({
  range: true,
  min: parseInt($("#maxAge").attr('min')), //get it like this and then pasre it..as integer
  max: parseInt($("#maxAge").attr('max')),
  values: [parseInt($("#maxAge").attr('minVal')), parseInt($("#maxAge").attr('maxVal'))],
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $("#sliderVal").val(ui.values[0] + "-" + ui.values[1]);
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="maxAge" min="18" max="75" minVal="20" maxVal="45"></div>
<input type="text" class="slider-text text-right gradient-text mt-2" id="sliderVal" readonly>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example that makes use of Data Attributes.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#maxAge").slider({
    range: true,
    min: $("#maxAge").data('min'),
    max: $("#maxAge").data('max'),
    values: [
      $("#maxAge").data("min-value"),
      $("#maxAge").data('max-value')
    ],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#sliderVal").val(ui.values[0] + "-" + ui.values[1]);
    }
  });
  $("#sliderVal").val($("#maxAge").data("min-value") + "-" + $("#maxAge").data('max-value'));
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="maxAge" data-min="18" data-max="75" data-min-value="20" data-max-value="45"></div>
<input type="text" class="slider-text text-right gradient-text mt-2" id="sliderVal" readonly />
```

Data Attributes are a commonly used method to store data that is related to an element. You can easily call it using jQuery `.data()`.

See More:

https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: I have already found the solution from Swati's answer.. However, I see in the snippet that your solution works equally good too.. Therefore, +1 for you :)